# What is a Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've searched on Google, and I just found the *uses* of gem. As in, gem install, etc.

Are gems collections of .rb scripts?

If I build a series of scripts, for example that wraps the functionality of Google translate, is the preferred way of distributing that for usage a gem?

If not, how would I distribute this code?

Answer (score 39):

According to [RubyGems Wiki -](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems) RubyGems is a package manager for the Ruby programming language that provides a standard format for distributing Ruby programs and libraries (in a self-contained format called a "gem"), a tool designed to easily manage the installation of gems, and a server for distributing them.

The gem command is used to build, upload, download, and install Gem packages.
Gem Usage

RubyGems is very similar to apt-get, portage, and yum in functionality.

Installation:

```
gem install mygem
```

Uninstallation:

```
gem uninstall mygem
```

Listing installed gems:

```
gem list --local
```

Gem Package Building

The gem command may also be used to build and maintain .gemspec and .gem files.

Build .gem from a .gemspec file:

```
gem build mygem.gemspec
```

For more info, refer to [RubyGems Manuals](http://guides.rubygems.org/).

Comment: It says "a tool designed to easily manage the installation of gems" but what IS a gem was the question?

Comment: gem is nothing but a libary

Answer (score 10):

Here are some nice tutorials :)

<strike>http://railscasts.com/episodes/135-making-a-gem</strike>
http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler

A gem is a module/Library that you can install and use in every project on your server.
A plugin is a module/Library that you can use inside your project

Indeed, if you make some code what you like to share you can make a gem or plugin of it. You can publish it on for example github.com. You can check the source of the existing gems on github if you like to know how to make a gem as well.

Comment: Just as a note you should watch the _second_ link here, not the first. The first one is an outdated and ugly way.

Comment: I feel this is the actual answer. The one most voted seems to answer a different question.

Answer (score -1):

Gem Package Building

Step : gem build your_gem_name.gemspec

simple steps follow [click here](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/)